# Combinations and Permutations

Tags: combinatorics

Tom orders a dinner that comes with 2 side dishes. If there are 5 entrees and 6 side dishes available as options, how many different dinner combinations are possible?

Comment: Is Tom allowed to order 2 servings of the same side dish?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: This is a basic application of the [multiplication (or Chinese menu) principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

- How many ways are there for Tom to choose an entrée?
- How many ways are there for Tom to choose a pair of side dishes? Note that you’re just counting $2$-element subsets of the set of $6$ possible side dishes.
- How must you combine these two partial results to get the final answer?